# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] when adding a csv to Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

I just started learning python from linked learning and already stuck. I wanted to import my csv file from my desktop to Jupiter notebook. This is what I had:

```py
import pandas as pd

import os

print(os.getcwd())

pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\QQM2\Desktop\us_baby_names.csv")
```

But the result I got was :

```
/Users/QQM2

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-feae92e6bbe7> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\QQM2\Desktop\us_baby_names.csv")


pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\QQM2\\Desktop\\us_baby_names.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\QQM2\\Desktop\\us_baby_names.csv'
```

Comment: Did you verify that the path and file name matched exactly?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you should assign the file path in a variable like this

```
file1 = "C:\Users\QQM2\Desktop\us_baby_names.csv" 

# then while calling the file you should assign it in a variable as well: 

df = pd.read_csv(file1) 

# then print it: 

print(df.head())
```

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference. In fact, I think it should create issues of its own, due to the use of unescaped backslashes.